# Changing Kibana-index on the basis of the context

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, dashboard, kibana

I am a newbie to Computer science in general and at present I am working on a project which involves Elasticsearch, logstash, and Kibana and we are using this to build up a centralized Logging system. 
In kibana config.js , there is a parameter kibana_index whose default value is set to "Kibana-int". Is there a way possible to change the value of Kibana-index based on the context? What I could understand from my research is that "kibana-int" is the index which stores all the dashboards. When I say context, what I mean is if I have multiple projects in an organization, the dropdown on kibana dashboard page should show the dashboards only under a particular project when I give that project's name as the context in my url. So people working in a project get to see only the ones in their project.
The only way I could find is to change the kibana-index value based on the project say something like "kibana-projA". So it shows all the dashboards under this particular index. But I couldnt find a way as to how to do it. Could you please help me out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is not Kibana feature that would let you dynamically pick the kibana_index.
In order to achieve your goal, you could setup separate Kibana instances with separate config.js configurations for the kibana_index property ([source code](https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/blob/master/src/config.js#L53)).
You could also serve Kibana with a server stack such as node.js or ruby on rails and have the server specify which kibana_index to use based on the user request.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, use a java script function instead of "kibana-int", so when kibana try to getting the value, the java script function gets invoked, write the logic inside the java script function which decides by looking into the window.document.url and decide appropriate index.

i hope this resolves your problem

Comment: Thanks Ankireddy. I was able to do the same and was successful in changing the index based on the context. I specified the name of the project as query string.  Now I am working on something similar. Say I have a url like "logs.xyz.com/projname", I should get the projname from this url. Projname here is the pathname which can be extracted. But the problem is, when I type the url as "logs.xyz.com", I do get the Kibana page. But when I add the pathname, I get the error page which was not the case when I added the query string. Any help with this?

Comment: the reason that you are getting the exception is because of the no html exists with the given name. by default when you try to access the kibana it loads the index.html only